# Does genital customization matter in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

In the character creation screen there is an option to add a penis to your character, regardless if you've chosen a male or a female character.

[image]

There is also an additional option to customize the type of penis you choose as well as the size of the penis. That said, with a few hours into the game I haven't seen anything meaningful that would make these options noticeable.  During sex scenes with Joytoys my large penis isn't noticeably visible and I haven't seen any clothing options that would make any changes made obvious.

So is there even a point to having a penis?  Does my penis size matter, or does the type of penis I have have any functionality within the game? Besides the character roleplay, I haven't seen any meaningful in-game interaction which makes use of the feature...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I am aware genital size does nothing except when you are nude. It may affect romance possibly, but I as far as I have seen it doesn’t.

Answer (score 9):

There is no impact by the genital customization. But your voice and body type very much does affect your romance options due to side characters having sexual preferences:

> - *Panam Palmer* only romanceable with a masculine body type 
>  - *Kerry Eurodyne* only romanceable with a masculine voice and body type
>  - *Judy Alvarez* only romanceable with a feminine body type and voice tone
>  - *River Ward* only romanceable with a feminine body type
>  - *Meredith Stout* romanceable with all body types (requires story-decision)

Source: [Gamesradar](https://www.gamesradar.com/cyberpunk-2077-romance-sex-relationships/)